# question on initialization of Manipulate, Dynamic, Refresh

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I use the following pattern in Manipulate

```
Dynamic[Refresh[....logic to handle v changes...., TrackedSymbols->{v}]]
```

in setting up the logic.

I use the above to represent an 'event handler', where 'v' is the control variable that the user changes. So, When a specific control variable changes, there is specific code to take care of the logic needed to handle this one variable being changed. This simulates 'callback' in other GUI programming systems.

This works very well. Except at initialization time, since Manipulate will 'fire' these refreshes when Manipulate first come up on the screen, even without me changing the slides.

Also, the order in which it decides to 'fire' the refresh can not be depended on. This makes it hard to initialize the state of the program.

Here is an example

```
Manipulate[

 Row[{
   Dynamic[Refresh[Print["x changed"]; {x, y, z}, TrackedSymbols -> {x}]],
   Dynamic[Refresh[Print["y changed"];  "", TrackedSymbols -> {y}]],
   Dynamic[Refresh[Print["z changed"];  "", TrackedSymbols -> {z}]]
   }
  ]
 ,
 {{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 10},
 {{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 10},
 {{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 10}
 ]
```

If you run the above, you'll notice the 3 print messages come up, without touching the controls.

My question: is there a way to prevent this initial refresh? I want the refresh code to run when I actually change the variable using the slider.

You might say, what is the big deal, let it refresh initially and run the logic as if the variables did change by the user.

Yes, I do that now. but I am trying to make it more efficient by reducing unnecessary work. Since the code will run some long computation each time a control variable changes, and this makes the Manipulate take more time than needed when it first come up, since the computation in each control variable has to run once.

I can introduce an extra 'state variable' to control this, and check that all events has 'fired' once, by counting, before starting the real work. Once all events fire once, I can set this variable to True, and only run the real code when the event fires and this state variable is true as well.

But I thought to ask if there might be a build-in way or smarter way to handle this without introducing more complicated logic in the code as I could not find an option or a setting to handle this.

Thanks,

Comment: If I run your example for the first time I even get 6 print messages.

Comment: You are correct, it prints 6 times, not 3 times. It is always interesting to try to figure why that is. In other words, the expression of Manipulate was evaluated 2 times initially before even using Manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is not really general and not pretty and just a workaround, but it does what you want:

```
  Manipulate[Module[{refx, refy, refz}, 
   If[{x,y,z} == {1,1,1}, {x, y, z}, 
    Row[{Dynamic[Refresh[
        Print["x changed"]; 
         {x, y, z}, TrackedSymbols -> 
         {x}]], Dynamic[Refresh[
        Print["y changed"]; "", 
        TrackedSymbols -> {y}]], 
      Dynamic[Refresh[
        Print["z changed"]; "", 
        TrackedSymbols -> {z}]]}]]], 
  {{x, 1, "x"}, 0, 10}, 
  {{y, 1, "y"}, 0, 10}, 
  {{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, even though I can not use it. It uses SetAttributes, which is not an allowed Symbol in demonstrations.

Comment: btw, it is my mistake, I should have mentioned that before, about the SetAttribute. There are a number of functions and Symbols not allowed to be used in demos (CDF will not build). Security reasons.

Comment: I fixed it. But why are you using CDF? I prefer webMathematica.

Comment: @Rolf I'd say CDF and webMathematica are two different worlds: one client-side, the other server-side, one freely downloadable, the other buyware, one a simple save from Mathematica, the other ???

Comment: @Sjoerd there is a free amateur license of webMathematica. Granted, it is *much* more work to make a webMathematica site, but there is nothing to download at all! Just browser. ( shameless ad: I am giving a talk   about a webMathematica project at the conference next month ).

Comment: @Sjoerd not that CDF is not a great idea for certain things. But as the OP question shows, it is quite limited for more advanced use cases. Or you have to reprogram. But no data-in-out is already liming things quite a bit. Of course, with the Pro-CDF-version things will probably improve, from a programmer point of view.

Comment: @Rolf agreed. One thing that comes to  mind is the use without browsers. You can use a CDF demonstration as a standalone application and use it *sans* internet. An advantage of webMathematica on the other hand might be DRM. BTW I'm thinking of going to the conference, so perhaps we might meet there.